# WordPress WooCommerce Polylang перевод двух слов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

Как перевести Flat rate и Other?
Flat rate - фиксированная сумма.
Orher - другое.

Я не понимаю, как перевести это, чтобы другое было. По сути, нужно прям где-то поменять их название, а не конкретно в том месте и тогда изменится везде. Но как это сделать, точнее где.

Пользуюсь плагином Polylang.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это стандартные строки WooCommerce и они уже переведены. При смене локали должны подтянуться нужные переводы

Comment: Но этого не происходит.